# sqlite database resets on each compile and run

Tags: sqlite, ios-simulator

I have built up a basic database application in which user can insert records onto a table and app displays them on a TableView.

Everything is working as it is supposed to be. For example, the new records do display even if we kill the app from app switcher and relaunch it from the springboard.

BUT every time I build and run using Xcode, the database just goes to default records! The new records are just not there.

Is it normal?... but what if I want to test my app for new records? Any fix?

BTW, JFYI, below is the code I use to make editable DB.

```
-(NSString *)createEditableDatabase{
// Check if DB already exists
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.db"];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];

//The editable DB already exists
if (success) {
    return writableDB;
}


//The editable DB does not exist
//Copy the default DB into App's Doc Dir.

NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.db"];

success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writableDB error:&error];

if (!success) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable DB file: '%@'", [error localizedDescription]);
}
return writableDB;
```

}

Comment: The code looks like as if you always run into the "copy default db", you should use an else part for the first `if(success)...`.

Comment: @Rajat Bansal hard to tell whats going wrong there, can you put NSLogs into your code and see for yourself when the db exists, dumping the filepath etc and see when it gets copied from the default db?

Comment: @Nick Actually, I did use NSLog to confirm that code is not executing beyond the return statement in if, so it does finds the database to be there in writable path! But then why no new records?!
I think I need to dig deeper. Will update soon.

Comment: Persisting to the db works? You should open your db with a tool in the App folder an confirm that data has been written to it.

Comment: While digging deeper, I noticed that the database modify date in finder was not updating when I inserted a record. So, I found out that I was still using old path to perform DB operations (not the Documents one). :) 

Now everything working fine.

Anyways thanks Nick

Comment: Very good, you may want to post an answer here and accept it for yourself so the question is marked as finished.

Comment: yea... tried that earlier but couldn't do that time due to some 8 hour limit. Now even cant mark it as answer for 20 hours... LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While digging deeper, I noticed that the database modify date in finder was not updating when I inserted a record. So, I found out that I was still using old path to perform DB operations (not the Documents one). :) Now everything working fine. Anyways thanks Nick